# JS swapping an image smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I already have a function to swap the images, but they swap without any animation. Now I want a function witch swaps the images with a fading. Here is my written code for the swap function:

```
var header = new Array();
header[0] = "images/lan/IMG_2799.jpg";
header[1] = "images/lan/IMG_2816.jpg";


var x = 0;

function swapHeader() {
    document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + header[x] + ")";
    if (x < header.length - 1) x++; else x = 0;
    setTimeout("swapHeader()", 5000);
}
window.onload=swapHeader;
```

Comment: You can only fade between 2 images, so a background image would never work, try a div with 2 absolute positioned `img` elements in it, and fade between them - changing the image of the hidden `img` element to the 'next' image.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use two elements, one per image. Then, slowly increase and decrease the opacity (a CSS property) of the one on top. The rest of your content should go above those two elements, and have a transparent background.